# sum all item in vector v

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I'm trying to complete a programming challenge after learning about templates. The directions are:

> Write a function.
>
> T accum(vector v)
>
> that forms and returns the "sum" of all items in the vector v passed to it. For example, if T is a numeric type such as int or double, the numeric sum will be returned, and if T represents the STL string type, then the result of concatenation is returned.
>
> NOTE: For any type T, the expression T() yields the value or object created by the default constructor. For example, T() yields the empty string object if T is the string class. If T represents a numeric type such as int, then T() yields 0. Use this fact to initialize your "accumulator."
>
> Test your function with a driver program that asks the user to enter three integers, uses accum to compute the sum, and prints out the sum. The program than asks the user to enter three strings, uses accum to concatenate the strings, and prints the result.

Here is what I have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>


using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T accum(vector <T> v) {
    T sum;

    for (auto iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); iter++) {
        sum += *iter;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    int intInput;
    vector<string> myStrings;
    string strInput;

    cout << "Enter 3 number to be added together." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Enter number " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> intInput;
        vec.push_back(intInput);
    }
    cout << accum(vec) << endl;

    cout << "Enter 3 words to be concantinated." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Enter word " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> strInput;
        myStrings.push_back(strInput);
    }
    cout << accum(myStrings) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the error:

> uninitialized local variable "sum" used.

I have tried other approaches like using `at()`. How can I accomplish this for both data types?

Comment: *How can I accomplish this for both data types?* -- First, there is already a function for this: [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).  Second, your error about not initializing a variable is not a true compiler error, it is a warning.

Comment: I ran across that when I was looking for answers online. We have not learned that, and to me it seems the point here is to build our own version of it.

Comment: That is a pretty nice error message. Does `T sum;` look initialized to you? See cppref [Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization).

Comment: Well do what `std::accumulate` does -- pass the initial value as a parameter and set `sum` to it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I don't understand why += doesn't concantenate or add the values.

Comment: First, `sum` may or may not be initialized, depending on what type `T` is.  Second, using an uninitialized variable is a logical error, it is not a compile-time error.

Comment: `std::accumulate(begin(v), end(v), T{})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that `sum` is initialized to the default value, you can do the following:

```
T sum = {};
```

or

```
 T sum = T();
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Can you explain why this is necessary in this case? Why can you not just do T sum += *iter;

Comment: @KennethFreeman You should read up on initialization, and what it means.

Comment: @KennethFreeman If `T` is a type such as `int`, `char`, `double`, etc.  Then the value is uninitialized if you don't initialize them.  No different if you did: `{ int x; cout << x; }` what do you think will be printed?  You don't know, since `x` is not initialized.  If `T` is a class that has a default constructor, then `T sum;` *is* initialized due to the default constructor being invoked.  So to ensure, regardless of the type, that `T` is initialized, you "force" the default initialization yourself.

Comment: @KennethFreeman This is very clearly explained in the NOTE paragraph of the instructions you were given: "*For any type T, the expression T() yields the value or object created by the default constructor... **Use this fact to initialize your accumulator**.*" You need to pay closer attention to requirements when they are given to you.

Comment: Remy, I read it but didn't understand what it meant. Sorry, I'm sure you never had problems when learning. I'm glad stackoverflow is full of people who are so respectful to people trying to learn something new.

Comment: OK, Thanks for that Paul. I guess I wasn't wrapping my head around it being treated like a class. When I read the note I thought I might need to create a class that accum() was a member of.